# How to export AGGrid data to excel using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, ag-grid

I have an AGGrid in my application and I want to export the data from the grid into excel using Selenium

I got this API reference
**this.gridApi.exportDataAsExcel();**

on https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/excel-export/

however, I am not able to figure out how to use this API in my Selenium script (using Java)

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the Grid API via automation / end to end testing.

What I recommend you do is that you can have a button that's showing or a div that is hidden from the screen.

Using Selenium, you can click on the button and write a click handler to call `api.exportDataAsExcel()`